# ASP.Net MVC 3 - Alter URL mid POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Let's say I have an action like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(MyObject obj)
{
  //Do a SQL insert that gets an Id for obj

  //Do some long-running operation in the background - don't wait for it to finish

  //Return a report of the object
  return View(obj);
}
```

Is there a way to modify the URL after the POST so it will display `?id=1234` at the end? There is an equivalent action for doing a GET (as if the user shared the page), and I'd like to just display the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `RedirectResult` and redirect the user to the new URL.

If you do that you can't pass anything to the view though.

A common practice is to store it in the `TempData` variable:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(MyObject obj)
{
  //Do a SQL insert that gets an Id for obj

  //Do some long-running operation in the background - don't wait for it to finish
  TempData["obj"] 0 obj;
  //Return a report of the object
  return new RedirectResult();
}
```

You can't programmatically change the URL from the server.
If you don't want to use a redirect, you could change it with JavaScript once the page has loaded

Comment: I used the javascript option you mention, I did not want to run a new action yet.